# Equals and CompareTo contract mismatch

Tags: java, object, collections, equals

I am working on my project and need to override tostring, equals and hashcode method. But after doing that, values in object are not iterated, searched properly and I am suspecting issue on these methods only. Please look into below class and help to find out what may be issue in the contracts between these method.

```
public class Range implements Comparable<Range> {
    private BigDecimal first;
    private BigDecimal last;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
      Range range = (Range) o;
        return Objects.equals(first, range.first) &&
                Objects.equals(last, range.last);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(first, last);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Range r) {
        int value = 0;

        if (first.compareTo(r.last) > 0) {
          value = -1;
        } else if (last.compareTo(r.first) < 0) {
          value = 1;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

The place where it failing is when I am getting value where class object is saved as map key and value is string than absent value presence check is returning true.

private Map<Range, String> maps = new TreeMap<>();
// findRange(range) - Return says value present for eerything

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem** or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: **[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Comment: The equality implementation is fine, but the `compareTo` implementation violates the transitivity requirement. When it returns zero for `a` and `b`, as well as for `b` and `c`, then it must return zero for comparing `a` and `c` as well.

Comment: @Holger Can you suggest the code changes please

Comment: There is no simple code change. You can not create a `compareTo` method that allows you to handle overlapping ranges in that way. The contract requires a total order. Since ranges have no natural order at all, don’t implement a `compareTo` method. You can create different `Comparator`s, e.g. one for the starting point and one for the end point. When the collection has no overlapping ranges, searching for the highest start point lower or equals to the search term would be sufficient already. Otherwise, you’d have to do more than one search, to find a subset.

Answer (score 0):

There is no natural total ordering for ranges, because there is both the start and end of the range to consider.

You have to pick *something* that can be consistent with your equals, like:

- Compare starts first: if they are unequal, put the range with the smaller start first;
- The compare ends: if they are unequal, put the range with the smaller end first;
- Otherwise, they're equal.

Your current comparator is comparing firsts with lasts, and lasts with firsts, but that's not what you're doing in your equals/hashCode method.

You'd need to do something like:

```
int value;

value = first.compareTo(r.first);
if (value != 0) return value;

value = last.compareTo(r.last);
if (value != 0) return value;

return 0;
```

Comment: By making these changes, now findRange method is failing if value present

Comment: @OPTIMUS you've not shown the `findRange` method.

Comment: It is normal JPA method like findRange(range) which is mentioned on last 2 lines of question

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "normal JPA method like `findRange(range)`. Do you mean that you want to find a range that... equals? intersects? contains? abuts? the input range?